# Post string request volley?

Tags: json, string, http, escaping, android-volley

I want to `POST` the following string to a server and receive a JSONObject via android volley! The documentation says the request to the server should be in the format given below, with `Content-Type` as `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. How do I make this request with volley?

```
{
    Username=usr&Password=passwd&grant_type=passwd
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First you should Override your getbody()   and in that function encode your parameteres... for example:

```
    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("password", "yourpassword");

        if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
           return encodeParameters(params, getParamsEncoding());
        }
        return null;
    }


        protected byte[] encodeParameters(Map<String, String> params, String paramsEncoding) {
        StringBuilder encodedParams = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), paramsEncoding));
                encodedParams.append('=');
                encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), paramsEncoding));
                encodedParams.append('&');
            }
            return encodedParams.toString().getBytes(paramsEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + paramsEncoding, uee);
        }
    }
```

this the way to encode your parameters.... volley actually has implemented the following function, and it works, for me it works... hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

So your question is confusing. POST body parameters aren't encoded inside a JSON body.

I haven't tested it but if you understand HTTP you should understand the rest from here.

```
final Map<String, String> postBody = new HashMap<String, String>();
postBody.put("Username", "usr");
postBody.put("Password", "passwd");
postBody.put("grant_type", "passwd");

final Listener<JSONObject> responseListener = ...;
Request request = new Request<JSONObject>(Method.POST, "http://example.com", errorListener) {

   void deliverResponse(JSONObject obj) {
         responseListener.onResponse(obj);
   }

   protected Map<String, String> getPostParams() throws AuthFailureError {
         return postBody;
   }

   protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
         if (response.status == 200) {
             JSONObject responseBody = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
             return Response.success(body, getCacheEntry());
         } else {
             return new Response<JSONObject>(new VolleyError(response);
         }
   }

};
requestQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: Don't know how to include a linebreak like you did(android studio) - I used "{\nUsername=usr&Password=passwd&grant_type=passwd\n}" but I'm getting a bad request error!!

Comment: are you sure it's a json body and not a www-url-encoded parameter expected? Those look like www-url-encoded params to me, with braces around them.  json would have defined each as a separate key-value without the &'s.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I want to send this string as x-www-form-urlencoded parameter and receive a json response, if that's what you're asking!!

Comment: a www-url-encoded parameter is expected at the server!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion again, while researching, I must have confused the word "encoding"! I've clarified the question - please let me know if we're on the same page! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yep that should do it. I believe the default encoding in volley is www form url encoded. Yeah no worries content type confusion happens a lot.